# Sending mail with attachment(image) using sendmail in Linux(ksh)

Tags: sendmail, images, html

I am trying to send a mail with below command. I am sending this command from sqr to the command line, which is working fine. `$FilePath_mail` have `To`,`From` and other information along with mail body which is in HTML format. I want to have an image (logo) in the body, so I wanted to send it as an attachment.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t < $FilePath_mail
```

I need to change the above command to add the attachment(basically an image) to the mail?

Comment: Pure sendmail doesn't support attachments, use `mutt` instead.

Comment: sendmail does not care what you send. But if you want attachments you need to handle the MIME encoding yourself. If we can choose not to use sendmail then mail or mailx would be more lightweight than mutt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image as a MIME part to the mail and then reference it using the `Content-ID` (CID) already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405611/3703638)

The people behind [Courier MTA](http://www.courier-mta.org/) have made the utility [makemime](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/makemime.html). It will be installed as part of Courier MTA but on some systems it is an independent package or as part of the [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) utility.

The `makemime` makes it easier to MIME encode your mail messages from the commandline. The example from their page is:

> For example:

```
# Take two files containing the text and the html version of a message, and
# add MIME headers to them.

makemime -c "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" -o tmp1.txt msg.txt
makemime -c "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" -o tmp1.html msg.html

# Combine the result into a multipart/alternative collection

makemime -m "multipart/alternative" -a "Content-Disposition: inline" \
                                -o tmp.ma1 tmp1.txt
makemime -j tmp.ma1 -o tmp.ma2 tmp1.html

# Add MIME headers to an image attachment.

makemime -c "image/gif" -a "Content-Disposition: attachment" \
                        -o tmp2.gif attachment.gif

# Create the final multipart/mixed collection

makemime -m "multipart/mixed" -a "Mime-Version: 1.0" \
                              -o tmp.mm1 tmp.ma2
makemime -j tmp.mm1 -o output.msg tmp2.gif
```

> output.msg now contains the complete MIME collection. Just add the Subject:, From:, and To: headers (can also be done by additional -a options, of course), and send it on its way.

This is what you are asking - and it can be done. Using a tool like `makemime` makes the process fairly safe.

You should however read the Sendgrid article on ["How to Embed Images in Your Emails: The Facts"](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/). Because of poor handling in many clients I usually just end up referencing the image on a web server. It is the easiest method and even though it often requires the user to "click to view" it seems to give the most consistent results across clients.

Another option is to inline embed the logo in your HTML source.

```
 <img alt="Logo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,">
```

or

```
 <img alt="Logo" src="data:image/png;base64,"
```

Add the base64 encoded data of the image file right after `base64,` and you are good to go. But again many clients will not like it.

You can encode the file online with [base64encode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/). I would highly recommend to compress the image first using something like [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you opt just for sending the image, you can always send an image via email with `mpack`

The syntax as you need it, is roughly:

```
mpack -s "This is my image" $FilePath_mail bill@domain.com
```

From `man mpack`

> NAME
>
> ```
>    mpack - pack a file in MIME format
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The mpack program encodes the the named file in one or more MIME messages.   The
>          resulting messages are mailed to one or more recipients, written to a named file
>          or set of files, or posted to a set of newsgroups.

In Debian, you install it as in:

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
```